# CakePHP appending to form data on submit

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I have page that adds people. A person has a name, date of birth, etc. A person can also have many phone numbers, and many addresses (Home and/or Postal).  In my view I have some jQuery which allows the user to add additional phone numbers and addresses to a new person record.  There is no limit to how many they can add.

Currently what I am doing is, when the form is submitted jQuery is taking all the phone numbers and addresses, converting them into into JSON and inserting them into a hidden field.  In the controller this JSON data is then converted into a PHP array and then appended to the rest of the data before calling saveAll on it.

My question is, is this the best way to achieve this?  Is there a way to have this data submitted to the controller like the rest of the form data so that I don't need to do anything in the controller other than call saveAll on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. When you add the fields with jQuery, you just need to stick to Cake's naming conventions.

The 'name' attribute of your input fields should be of the form:

```
data[ModelName][X][field_name]
```

where X is an integer, representing the number of that record. Eg. if you had 3 associated addresses, each with a `line_1` and `line_2` field, your generated fields should look like:

```
<input type=​"text" name=​"data[Address]​[1]​[line_1]​" id=​"Address1Line1">​
<input type=​"text" name=​"data[Address]​[1]​[line_2]​" id=​"Address1Line2">​
<input type=​"text" name=​"data[Address]​[2]​[line_1]​" id=​"Address2Line1">​
<input type=​"text" name=​"data[Address]​[2]​[line_2]​" id=​"Address2Line2">​
<input type=​"text" name=​"data[Address]​[3]​[line_1]​" id=​"Address3Line1">​
<input type=​"text" name=​"data[Address]​[3]​[line_2]​" id=​"Address3Line2">​
```

Note that X isn't an id or anything - it's just a number used to make a distinction between the different records when there are more than one from the same model.

If you stick to Cake's conventions, Cake with just handle it automatically in the controller.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did think about doing that. My setup for addresses for example is a single set of fields that adds an address to a table inside the add person page. Rather than generating a new set of fields each and every time the user wishes to add another address. It had crossed my mind to create a set of hidden fields for these new addresses that were added to the table which would then be appended to the post data, however I decided it would be easier to manage and more elegant to just use JSON in a hidden field. I was hoping to inject this JSON data into the form data somehow.

Comment: In that case it sounds like the way you're doing it is just fine.

Comment: Actually I've had a think about your suggestion and I now believe it's the way to go. By appending a set of hidden fields to the table row containing the data to be submitted I reduce a lot of jQuery and JSON overhead. Especially when it comes to creating, updating, and deleting rows. It also means cake does it's thing and appends the data without me jumping through several hoops. Thanks again for the reply, it gave me the circuit breaker I needed.